# Improving speed for calculating eigenvalues of a sequence of large matrices

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I need to compute the eigenvalues of matrices of size 1000x1000. I create two symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ where each entry $(i,j)$ is given by a function ($f$ for $A$ and $g$ for $B$) of $i,j$ and a parameter $n$ over which I will later sum. The functions $f$ and $g$ are essentially Gauss Hypergeometric functions:

```
f[i_,j_,n_] := Hypergeometric2F1[0.5, 0.5, N[i-j+1], 1.-(L+1.)/n];
g[i_,j_,n_] := Hypergeometric2F1[-0.5, 1.5, N[i-j+1], 1.-(L+1.)/n]
```

Creating these two 1000x1000 matrices takes already a fair amount of time. Then I repeat the process for some different values of $n$, computing the eigenvalues of the matrix product $C=A.B$. At the end, I use these eigenvalues to compute some quantity $R$.

Here is the code I have written:

```
Do[
  L = 10*k;
  R = 0;
  ti = SessionTime[];

  Do[   
   (* Creating symmetric matrices A and B *)
   Atmp = ParallelTable[f[i,j,n], {i, 1, 1000}, {j, 1, i}];
   Btmp = ParallelTable[g[i,j,n], {i, 1, 1000}, {j, 1, i}];
   A = MapThread[Join, {Atmp, Rest /@ Flatten[Atmp, {{2}, {1}}]}];
   B = MapThread[Join, {Btmp, Rest /@ Flatten[Btmp, {{2}, {1}}]}];

   C = A.B;

   (* Eigenvalues of C *)
   Ev = Re[Eigenvalues[C]];

   (* Some computation with Ev *)
   Rint = 0;
   Do[
    If[Ev[[i]] > 1/2, Rint += Log[Ev[[i]]-1/2]];
    , {i, 1, 1000}];

   R += Rint;

   If[n == L, Print[L , "\t", R, "\t", SessionTime[] - ti, "s"]];

   , {n, 1, L}];

  , {k, 1, 20}];
```

For $L=10$ (ie $k=1$ in the first Do), it takes around 9500s, for $L=40$ it takes 61 000s, and so on.. For larger values of $L$, it will take several days! I cannot seem to find how to speed things up (ParallelDo does not improve the speed). An idea may be to compute the eigenvalues of my $L$ matrices at the same time in some sort of vectorized way, but I am not sure if it is possible or if it even makes sense.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Would you please also post the defintions of `f` and `g`?

Comment: A quick thought.  Are you using exact arithmetic when you don't need it?

Comment: No, I use MachinePrecision numbers everywhere. I will post simplified $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 1):

Because of floating point underflow, it might not be a good idea to use machine precision numbers. This is why I define `f` and `g` like this.

```
f[i_, j_, n_, L_] := 
  Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/2, i - j + 1, 1 - (L + 1)/n];
g[i_, j_, n_, L_] := 
  Hypergeometric2F1[-1/2, 3/2, i - j + 1, 1 - (L + 1)/n];
```

The matrices `A` and `B` are symmetric Toeplitz matrices and hence only their first row has to be computed. This cuts down the number of evaluations of `f` and `g` considerably.

We can obtain the matrices like this

```
prec = 20;
size = 1000;
n = 1;
L = 10;

a = Developer`ToPackedArray[N@f[Range[size], N[1, prec], n, L]];
b = Developer`ToPackedArray[N@g[Range[size], N[1, prec], n, L]];
A = ToeplitzMatrix[a, a];
B = ToeplitzMatrix[b, b];
```

Afterwards, you compute `Tr[A.B]` in a very expensive way by computing `A.B` and its eigenvalues. However, the trace is nothing but the Frobenius inner product of `A` with `B` and it can be computed from `a` and `b` without even assembling `A` and `B`:

```
mult = 2. Range[N[size], 1., -1];
mult[[1]] = N[size];

(a mult).b == Tr[A.B]
```

> True

This is how the whole code looks like after refactorization (I also dropped the printing of intermediate results).

```
f[i_, j_, n_, L_] := Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/2, i - j + 1, 1 - (L + 1)/n];
g[i_, j_, n_, L_] := Hypergeometric2F1[-1/2, 3/2, i - j + 1, 1 - (L + 1)/n];

size = 100;
mult = 2. Range[N[size], 1., -1];
mult[[1]] = N[size];

prec = 20;

data = ParallelTable[
Table[
 Block[{a, b, time, val, tic, toc},
  tic = SessionTime[];
  a = Developer`ToPackedArray[N@f[Range[size], N[1, prec], n, L]];
  b = Developer`ToPackedArray[N@g[Range[size], N[1, prec], n, L]];
  val = (a mult).b;
  toc = SessionTime[];
  {L, n} -> {"Value" -> val, "Time" -> toc - tic, "Kernel" -> $KernelID}
  ]
 , {n, 1, L}]
, {L, 10, 100, 10}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

For `size = 100`, this runs through in about 12.5 seconds on my Quad Core CPU.

Note that this algorithm has linear complexity in `size` while yours had cubic complexity due to the use of `Eigenvalues` and the matrix-matrix product (if you don't count these in then it was quadratic due to the way the matrices `A` and `B` were generated).

The slowest part here remains the evaluation `Hypergeometric2F1`. Maybe one can utilize some functional equations to reduce the number of evaluation needed. I don't know.

Comment: I should have said that I actually require the eigenvalues of $A.B$ because I compute some quantity with it, not only the trace as it seems. I will modify my post to clarify this. Henrik, is there a way to get the eigenvalues kand keeping a linear complexity as you did?

Comment: Maybe there is. I don't know. You can do the weirdest things with Toeplitz matrices and I am definiately not an expert in those.

Comment: I will look into it. Can you also explain your first comment "Because of floating point underflow, it might not be a good idea to use machine precision numbers."?

Comment: Ah, that was because at least `g` threw underflow errors when I was trying to call it with `size = 1000`. That happens when a floating point operation returns a value whose modulus is below `$MinMachineNumber` (that's approximately `2.22507*10^-308`).

Comment: Henrik, this line:  {L, n} -> <|"Value" -> val, "Time" -> toc - tic, "Kernel" -> $KernelID|>  produces an error with MMA 9.0 ( Syntax::sntxb: Expression cannot begin with "<|Value->val".)

Comment: Ah, `Association`s were intoduced in version 10, so we have to resort to a list of rules. (Fixed it.)